# DataGrid column headers, cant style properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to change the padding and colors of a DataGrid's column headers. The padding works fine but if I change the background color the cell grippers dissappear and there is no longer mouse over or mouse pressed affects on the cells. Here's what I am doing -

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF7F7F7">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,10,20,10"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFAACCFF"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Anybody know how to change the background color properly? I would also like to change the colors of the mouse over and mouse pressed events. I think it has something to do with triggers, anyone know?

Edit: Here is a picture of what my DataGrid header looks like, as you can see no grippers and no mouseover color change (it doesnt show in the screenshot but my mouse is on top of Property2). [image]

Comment: what additional stuff do you have between the <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle> for example I see .... just curious if you left something out that we may need to see here check this previous post out.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001235/wpf-datagrid-headertemplate-mysterious-padding

Comment: Oops, those dots were supposed to be after the closing </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>. Ill edit it.

Comment: Strage, everything works for me. Try on Putting Opacity = .5 into your style and see what heppens. All makes sense.

Comment: ok I tried putting opacity 0.5 in and it just fades out the background color and the text. No sign of the grippers, and the background doesnt change on mouseover/mousepressed.

Answer (score 0):

Something you might consider is changing the row color during the Row PrePainting or Row PostPainting event; it should give you better control on some of the smaller things you want to do and allow you to customize it based on the values in the grid/row.

Comment: I want to do everything in xaml. And I specifically need to change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to define your own `ControlTemplate` for `DataGridColumnHeader`. Inside that template define your own gripper and color.

As you mentioned you can use triggers to change color inside control template. Internet is full of examples which uses triggers to change color for example take a look at [this post](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/03/06/How-do-I-change-an-items-appearance-on-mouseover-in-WPF.aspx)

Comment: If go to Edit ColumnHeaderStyle>>Edit a Copy and change the background in the <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:DataGridHeaderBorder> element I run into the same problem - The grippers don't show up and the mouseover and mousepressed events dont change the background color.