# WPF DataGrid Strange Header Padding Behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, datagrid, padding

In the following Window, why does the header have a padding of 2/3 even though I explicitly set it to 0 using the following code? (And can see it as 0 in Snoop):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

This gives me the following (header has padding):

[image]

But as soon as I change it to something other than 0, e.g.:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

The padding doesn't get set to default. I am assuming there is some code somewhere in the WPF library?

[image]

Has someone come across this before and figured out why before I spend an afternoon finding out why?

Full Test Code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.GridSpacing"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Items>
                <system:String>Test</system:String>
            </DataGrid.Items>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="Test" 
                                       Background="Aquamarine"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Test" Background="Aquamarine"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see there is `DataGridHeaderBorder` above the `ContentPresenter` using **Live ViusalTree** in VS2015.

[image]

The **DataGridHeaderBorder** is the problem. You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001235/wpf-datagrid-headertemplate-mysterious-padding). In the [DataGridHeaderBorder.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework.Classic/parent/Shared/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/DataGridHeaderBorder.cs,1dc271873e6ddf1d),

```
/// <summary>
///     Positions children and returns the final size of the element.
/// </summary>
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
{
    if (UsingBorderImplementation)
    {
        // Revert to the Border implementation
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }

    UIElement child = Child;
    if (child != null)
    {
        // Use the public Padding property if it's set
        Thickness padding = Padding;
        if (padding.Equals(new Thickness()))
        {
            padding = DefaultPadding;
        }

        // Reserve space for the chrome
        double childWidth = Math.Max(0.0, arrangeSize.Width - padding.Left - padding.Right);
        double childHeight = Math.Max(0.0, arrangeSize.Height - padding.Top - padding.Bottom);

        child.Arrange(new Rect(padding.Left, padding.Top, childWidth, childHeight));
    }

    return arrangeSize;
}
```